# Change thumbnail size on public directory detail page

Tags: profile, images

We have a public directory that contains the contact image. By default the image thumbnail is set to a size of 100px X 100px. We would like this to be larger. Does anyone know where we can change that? I took a look at the css but did not see anything.

We are using WordPress 4.9.1 & CiviCRM 4.7.27.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that thumbnail size is set by CSS (at least it is in the backend), the actual contact image should be whatever size you uploaded the image at originally. Perhaps you can adjust the CSS to display those contact images at your desired size.

Based on your page, you could use:

```
.content img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

To set it to it's native size. You could alternatively used specific values (height: 200px; width: auto;) to be a little more uniform across different contact results.

Comment: I thought it was in the CSS but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Any chance you have a link you can share? I can take a quick poke.

Comment: Here is a page from a directory we are working with. https://storynet.org/find-a-storyteller/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/view&reset=1&id=326&gid=16

Comment: I threw some css in my previous answer.